# Solve for x in geometry diagram

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I found this problem online somewhere (cannot remember the exact source, sorry) and initially I thought it looked fairly simple and fun to solve. I've now sat for several hours and even asked some friends to help, but none of us can actually solve it (without complex algebraic equations). I am by no means an expert on geometry or trigonometric (or mathematics for that case), so I would assume there are some identities or theorems that would make this problem easier to solve that I just don't know. Can anyone help please. The problem is to solve for x in the below diagram (excuse the bad drawing in Paint): [image]

Comment: Hint: Look for similar triangles and use Pythagoras' theorem. The result is a quartic equation for $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the attached figure one has

$\overline{CD}=\dfrac{10}{\cos(\alpha)};\space\space\overline{AB}=10+10\cos(\alpha);\space\space\overline{CB}=\dfrac{10}{\cos(\alpha)}+10$ which gives the Pythagorean equation in $\alpha$
$$10^2+(10+10\cos(\alpha))^2=(\dfrac{10}{\cos(\alpha)}+10)^2$$ Simplifying one has, putting $z=\cos(\alpha)$
$$z^4+2z^3+z^2-2z=1$$ whose approximated real roots are $0.88320$ and $-0.46899$  so we have
$$x=\overline{EB}=\overline{DB}\cos(\alpha)=10\cos(\alpha)\approx8.8320$$

[image]